# How to get only one answer if there is no match after loop

Tags: c#, loops

My code has a for loop in array and has if statement, and I want to get only one answer if there is no match.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i].GetSomeValue() >= 1 && i].GetSomeValue() <= 5)
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    else 
       Console.WriteLine("No data");
}
```

However, I get these:

```
No data
No data
No data
No data
```

I want only one "No data" if there is no match. 
I tried adding

```
    else break;
}
Console.WriteLine("No data");
```

But it does not work.

How do I get what I want?

Comment: Hello qoDoq, welcome to stackoverflow, please provide us what values are available in an array `arr[]` and what `GetSomeValue()` does? is it any extension method??

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is data in some but not all?

Comment: do you want to show no data if any of the element does not satisfy the condition. still this question is not clear to me...

Comment: Hello @PrasadTelkikar an `arr[]` has five arguments with different data types: in, string,  enum, decimal, datatime, and return value( int ) of the method, `GetSomeValue()`. The method calculates year difference, and returns int.

Comment: @iakobski I want to get values from the array that matches the condition.

Comment: I believe answer given by @AkbarAsghari will solve your problem

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yes, I am sorry for the ambiguous question, but your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative based on linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var withinSpecs = arr.Where(e => e.GetSomeValue() >= 1 && e.GetSomeValue() < 5).ToArray();
if(withinSpecs.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No data");
}
else
{
    foreach(var element in withinSpecs)
        Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted to use linq because it seems very convenient. But did not know how to implement it. But thank you for the alternative idea and will help my learning!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Use flag like This Code :

```
bool flag = false ;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i].GetSomeValue() >= 1 && arr[i].GetSomeValue() <= 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        flag=true;
    }
}

if(!flag)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No data");
}
```

Comment: Couple things: 1. a variable called 'flag' could be more descriptive. 2. The if statement could be cleaner if the meaning of flag was inverted -- it could be written as "if (flag)", avoiding the need for the logical not operator.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Don't check the no data condition until after the loop  
  int noData = -1;     
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].GetSomeValue() >= 1 && arr[i].GetSomeValue() <= 5) {
                        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
                        noData = 0;
                    }
                }
    if (noData == -1) {Console.WriteLine("No data");}
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting an int for a true/false condition? C# has boolean types!

Comment: The big pro of using a boolean instead of an integer is that the intent of a boolean is much clearer.

Comment: At least he didn’t declare an enumeration type with True, False as member names 

Comment: @theMayer I only do that when I need a tri-stated flag.

Comment: It would make sense to have an integer if it would count the number of matches. E.g. `int matches = 0; ... if (condition) { matches++; ...} ... if (matches == 0) Console.WriteLine("No data");`